# In Ag-Grid react how to check if cell value is present and if not how to create one?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-validation

I am new to react and Ag-Grid as well, I need to have two columns, Column-A and Column-B. In Column-A it should be text-box and Column-B should be a dropdown where the list of values are from Column-A, if the entered value is not present in Column-A a new row should be added,
ex:
Column-A | Column-B
10       |  10
20       |  10
30       |  20
40       |  70

Now in the above table for Column-B I have entered value as 70, but in Column-A the value 70 does not exist, hence it should create a new row with Column-A having value as 70 and leaving Column-B as empty, like below.
Column-A | Column-B
10       |  10
20       |  10
30       |  20
40       |  70
70       |

I did not got any idea for creating this functionality, please help me on this.